# How can I merge Python dictionaries by keys?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

Let's say I got two dictionaries in a list looks like below:

```
[
    {'country': 'United Kingdom',
    'city': 'Cambridge',
    'title': 'University of Cambridge',
    'region': 'Europe'},
    {'country': 'United States',
    'city': 'Cambridge',
    'title': 'Institute of Technology (MIT)',
    'region': 'North America'}
]
```

and I also have another two dictionaries (for each university's location) in a list below:

```
[
    {'title': 'University of Cambridge',
    'latitude': '52.1873962',
    'longitude': '0.1302958635475542'},
    {'title': 'Institute of Technology (MIT)',
    'latitude': '42.3582393',
    'longitude': '-71.09664602558988'},
]
```

How can combine these two lists to:

```
[
    {'country': 'United Kingdom',
    'city': 'Cambridge',
    'title': 'University of Cambridge',
    'region': 'Europe',
    'latitude': '52.1873962',
    'longitude': '0.1302958635475542'},
    {'country': 'United States',
    'city': 'Cambridge',
    'title': 'Institute of Technology (MIT)',
    'region': 'North America', 
    'latitude': '42.3582393',
    'longitude': '-71.09664602558988'}
]
```

What is the syntactically cleanest way to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip()` to pair off the dicts then merge them in a comprehension with something like:

```
d1 = [
    {'country': 'United Kingdom',
    'city': 'Cambridge',
    'title': 'University of Cambridge',
    'region': 'Europe'},
    {'country': 'United States',
    'city': 'Cambridge',
    'title': 'Institute of Technology (MIT)',
    'region': 'North America'}
]

d2 = [
    {'title': 'University of Cambridge',
    'latitude': '52.1873962',
    'longitude': '0.1302958635475542'},
    {'title': 'Institute of Technology (MIT)',
    'latitude': '42.3582393',
    'longitude': '-71.09664602558988'},
]

[{**a,**b} for a,b in zip(d1, d2)]
```

Which will give you:

```
[{'country': 'United Kingdom',
  'city': 'Cambridge',
  'title': 'University of Cambridge',
  'region': 'Europe',
  'latitude': '52.1873962',
  'longitude': '0.1302958635475542'},
 {'country': 'United States',
  'city': 'Cambridge',
  'title': 'Institute of Technology (MIT)',
  'region': 'North America',
  'latitude': '42.3582393',
  'longitude': '-71.09664602558988'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge two dictionaries using `**kwargs`

```
unis = [
    {'country': 'United Kingdom',
    'city': 'Cambridge',
    'title': 'University of Cambridge',
    'region': 'Europe'},
    {'country': 'United States',
    'city': 'Cambridge',
    'title': 'Institute of Technology (MIT)',
    'region': 'North America'}
]

locs = [
    {'title': 'University of Cambridge',
    'latitude': '52.1873962',
    'longitude': '0.1302958635475542'},
    {'title': 'Institute of Technology (MIT)',
    'latitude': '42.3582393',
    'longitude': '-71.09664602558988'},
]

combined_list = []
for i, v in enumerate(unis):
    combined_dict = {**v, **locs[i]}
    combined_list.append(combined_dict)
```

`print(combined_list)` outputs (formatted for visibility):

```
[
    {'country': 'United Kingdom',
     'city': 'Cambridge',
     'title': 'University of Cambridge',
     'region': 'Europe',
     'latitude': '52.1873962',
     'longitude': '0.1302958635475542'},

    {'country': 'United States',
     'city': 'Cambridge', 
     'title': 'Institute of Technology (MIT)', 
     'region': 'North America', 
     'latitude': '42.3582393', 
     'longitude': '-71.09664602558988'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we are to merge, we do not know the order in which the dictionaries appear nor can we claim that the first list is equivalent in length to the second list. Thus:

```
first = [
    {'country': 'United Kingdom',
    'city': 'Cambridge',
    'title': 'University of Cambridge',
    'region': 'Europe'},
    {'country': 'United States',
    'city': 'Cambridge',
    'title': 'Institute of Technology (MIT)',
    'region': 'North America'}
]
second = [
    {'title': 'University of Cambridge',
    'latitude': '52.1873962',
    'longitude': '0.1302958635475542'},
    {'title': 'Institute of Technology (MIT)',
    'latitude': '42.3582393',
    'longitude': '-71.09664602558988'},
]

a = {j['title']:j for j in second}
[{**i, **a[i['title']]} for i in first]

[{'city': 'Cambridge',
  'country': 'United Kingdom',
  'latitude': '52.1873962',
  'longitude': '0.1302958635475542',
  'region': 'Europe',
  'title': 'University of Cambridge'},
 {'city': 'Cambridge',
  'country': 'United States',
  'latitude': '42.3582393',
  'longitude': '-71.09664602558988',
  'region': 'North America',
  'title': 'Institute of Technology (MIT)'}]
```

Comment: It's definitely worth double checkin the assumption that the order is same both lists. If it's not, it's probably better to make a dict keyed to the `title` to avoid the O(n²)  complexity of the nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

This works using perge.

```
for i in range(len(x)):x[i].update(y[i])
```

output

````
[{'country': 'United Kingdom', 'city': 'Cambridge', 'title': 'University of Cambridge', 'region': 'Europe', 'latitude': '52.1873962', 'longitude': '0.1302958635475542'}, {'country': 'United States', 'city': 'Cambridge', 'title': 'Institute of Technology (MIT)', 'region': 'North America', 'latitude': '42.3582393', 'longitude': '-71.09664602558988'}]```
````

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that the order of the two lists might not always match, we cant just zip the lists together. Create a dict to allow O(1) look up of university data on the title element.

Then iterate the countries and if you find the matching title in the look up dict, merge the dicts.

```
countries = [
    {'country': 'United Kingdom',
    'city': 'Cambridge',
    'title': 'University of Cambridge',
    'region': 'Europe'},
    {'country': 'United States',
    'city': 'Cambridge',
    'title': 'Institute of Technology (MIT)',
    'region': 'North America'}
]

universities = [
    {'title': 'University of Cambridge',
    'latitude': '52.1873962',
    'longitude': '0.1302958635475542'},
    {'title': 'Institute of Technology (MIT)',
    'latitude': '42.3582393',
    'longitude': '-71.09664602558988'},
]

unidict = {u['title']: u for u in universities}
result = [{**c, **unidict[c['title']]} for c in countries if c['title'] in unidict]
print(result)
```

Result

```
[{'country': 'United Kingdom', 'city': 'Cambridge', 'title': 'University of Cambridge', 'region': 'Europe', 'latitude': '52.1873962', 'longitude': '0.1302958635475542'}, {'country': 'United States', 'city': 'Cambridge', 'title': 'Institute of Technology (MIT)', 'region': 'North America', 'latitude': '42.3582393', 'longitude': '-71.09664602558988'}]
```